# Stack Overflow Careers - Order by time posted

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs, sorting

There appears to be some change recently made to stack overflow careers.

In the past it was possible to order the search results by post time, now everything is listed under a company title.

It is difficult to identify which listings are new and which are old.  Under the new system, is it still possible to order by date posted? if so, how?

The search page looks like :

[image: Search page]

Answer (score 4):

Ah, I know what's happening here now. The results you're seeing are already newest-first, but for some reason they're missing the timestamp which usually appears on the right.

We're currently running an experiment with an updated search results view for some users, and I can see from the screenshot that you've been selected to see this new view. This new view doesn't include the timestamp - so that's definitely something we need to fix.

Comment: Is it A/B testing?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yep.

Answer (score 3):

This was initially by-design, as part of the A/B test we are doing with a new UI that emphasizes companies. But reading these comments made me re-think. So:

- We’ve put ‘date posted’ into the company-based view, same as the standard job-based view
- We’ll show the ‘most recent’ tab even if it’s the only available sort order. It acts as a label, if not a control.

It’s a better test, at the very least. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The dropdown has been replaced by a tab - just choose the "most recent" tab on the right.

[image]

Comment: Nice, I was also confused!

Comment: There do not appear to be any tabs - I have updated the question with a screen grab.

Comment: In your case you're searching by location, so the jobs are already returned most recent first.

Comment: @Kami Although, there should be a time to the right of the job listing - "1 hour ago", "3 days ago" etc.  What browser are you using?

Comment: @AlexWarren I on Chrome - Latest version.